# How to transform percentage cover data into species abundance data in algae

Tags: categorical-data, data-transformation, dataset, percentage, coverage-probability

I have collected percentage data for Rocky shore and summarised it per algae type like the example below:

```
        Low  Mid Mid-High High
Brown   23%  13%    3%    40%
Green    0%   8%   14%    18%
Red     12%   6%   12%     0%
```

How can I transform this percentage coverage data to species abundance data?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear this is a statistical question. You presumably need some biological/ecological model. If you were trying to back marginal counts out, that information is not in the table.